# Добавить стили к каждому nth-child элементу через jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть список элементов li,

`<ul class="portfolio-slider">
   <li> 
      <a class="portfolio-item"></a>
      <a href="" class="portfolio-item"> </a> 
   </li>
   <li> 
      <a class="portfolio-item"></a>
      <a href="" class="portfolio-item"> </a> 
   </li>
   ...
</ul>`

через jQuery нужно добавить к каждому первому свои свойства css,  к каждому второму - другие, к каждому третьему - третьи.

```
$('.portfolio-slider li:nth-child(1n)').find('a').first().css({
'top': '-300px',
'left': '-300px'
});
$('.portfolio-slider li:nth-child(1n)').find('a').eq(1).css({
    'top': '300px',
    'left': '-300px'
});

$('.portfolio-slider li:nth-child(2n)').find('a').first().css({
    'top': '-300px'
});
$('.portfolio-slider li:nth-child(2n)').find('a').eq(1).css({
    'top': '300px'
});

$('.portfolio-slider li:nth-child(3n)').find('a').first().css({
    'top': '-300px',
    'right': '-300px'
});
$('.portfolio-slider li:nth-child(3n)').find('a').eq(1).css({
    'top': '300px',
    'right': '-300px'
});
```

но добавляются свойства только в первый, второй и третий элементы li, а не в каждый первый, второй и третий.
http://jsfiddle.net/7PS7s/1/
Как сделать так, чтобы работало как нужно?

Answer (score 3):

```
:nth-child(3n-2) // Каждый первый
:nth-child(3n-1) // Каждый второй
:nth-child(3n) // Каждый третий
```